# Convert python turtle graphics number chain to name

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have been making a simple list function to make add a bunch of images for turtles to use, however I keep getting this error when running it: `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "<turtle.Turtle object at 0x000001C20E311D90>_1.gif": no such file or directory`

This is my code for it.

```
for i in Citygroups:
        i.up()
        wn.addshape(str(i)+'_1.gif')
        wn.addshape(str(i)+'_2.gif')
        wn.addshape(str(i)+'_3.gif')
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to convert the `<turtle.Turtle object at 0x000001C20E311D90>` to the name of the turtle. (IE: City_l1)

Comment: How did you set the turtle name? Where did you provide the value "City_I1" to your turtle?

Comment: City_L1 = t.Turtle(),
Then City_L1 is put into a list named Citygroups

Comment: You can't easily retrieve the name of the variable where something is contained. Maybe you could use a dictionary instead of a list and use the keys as their names. Would that work for you?

Comment: I've posted my commend as an answer in case you want to comment on it or [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to store the Turtle objects and use the keys as names:

```py
citygroups = dict()
citygroups["City_L1"] = t.Turtle()
# and so on...

for turtle_name, turtle_object in citygroups.items():
        turtle_object.up()
        wn.addshape(f"{turtle_name}_1.gif")
        wn.addshape(f"{turtle_name}_2.gif")
        wn.addshape(f"{turtle_name}_3.gif")
```